# In python, executing the runtime input in for loop it prints all values. why?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, input, runtime

I am new to python. I have executed for loop with runtime input.

**Loop 1:**

```
a = int(input("enter\n"))
for i in range(1, a+1):
      print(i)
```

The output prints all values from 1 to 5.

**Loop2:**

```
for i in range(1, 5):
         print(i)
```

The output print the values from 1 to 4.

Please someone explain the different between the above two for loop.

Comment: Code formatting

Answer (score 1):

In the range function in python, the last argument is exclusive. This means that it represents the stopping point of the range but is not included in the output. Since the first loop has a+1 as the last argument, a will be included in the output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/stdtypes.html#range ?

To keep things easy, `range(a, b)` will return an iterator that goes from `a` to `b - 1`.

Thus, your **first** loop will print *1* to *(a + 1) - 1 = a*, and your **second** loop will print *1* to *5 - 1 = 4*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,5):
    print(i)
```

> Prints values from 0 to 4 because when the iteration comes to the value 5 it becomes excluded and it won't print the value.

> So we add 1 to the final value(maximum) to print till the value we want.

```
for i in range(0,6):
     print(i)
```

**GIVES:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation